# Why forEachRow function doesn't affect the second page or next pages in dhtmx grid?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dhtmlx

I am tiring to format the the grid rows while loading itself. My aim is to make the row as ro while load the content with some condition. its working fine foe first page but it not happen for next pages of the grid. my detailed code is below. Any one knows the reason please share with me.

```
    mygrid.loadXML("xml/get_data.php?juid=" + juid,function(){

      mygrid.forEachRow(function(id){

       if (mygrid.cellById(id,22).getValue()==1) 
          {
                mygrid.setRowTextStyle(id,"color: red");
                mygrid.setRowExcellType(id,"ro");
          }


      });
```

Comment: Pagination code which i used is  'mygrid.enablePaging(true,19,15,"pagingArea",true);'

Comment: This may be solution...make one class file & define your function in that file and after that make object of that class to your php file & use that function..

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand completely.whats wrong with using this function in that file itself.one more thing where should i call the class file in grid loading php

Comment: instead of `forEachRow`, see if `forEachRowA` works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need this event:

```
mygrid.attachEvent("onPaging", function(count)
{
   someFunction();
});

function someFunction()
{
   mygrid.forEachRow(function(id){

      if (mygrid.cellById(id,22).getValue()==1) 
      {
            mygrid.setRowTextStyle(id,"color: red");
            mygrid.setRowExcellType(id,"ro");
      }

   });
}
```